# Cannot understand Android WebView documentation

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I find it's hard to follow Android WebView documentation. For example, what is the difference between `setMinimumLogicalFontSize` and `setMinimumFontSize`?

According to documentation:

`setMinimumLogicalFontSize:` Sets the minimum logical font size. The default is 8.

`setMinimumFontSize`: Sets the minimum font size. The default is 8.

Basically, it tells nothing, and I have no idea what is **font size** and what is **logical font size**.

Can anyone explain the meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the explanation not for android, but for iOS. I think it's the same thing:

> The minimum logical font size is the smallest font size that will
> display in a web view when the content’s font size is imprecisely
> specified. This includes content with logical sizes (such as small) or
> with a font size specified as a percentage of the default.

and

> minimumFontSize
>
> This sets the minimum display font size for the web view, overriding
> all content-specified styles, including explicitly specified font
> sizes.

[minimumLogicalFontSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpreferences/1536187-minimumfontsize) and [minimumFontSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpreferences/1536959-minimumlogicalfontsize)